# adding trailing zeros to php string if not in format

Tags: php

Have a text box which get data for price.
If someone enter something like "3." i want to get it converted to "3.0"
i cannot append "0" simply in the end because then if it is "100" gets converted to "1000"

Also is_numeric("3.") returns 1.

Whats the possible way round?

Comment: search for a decimal point being the last character in a the string, if it is, add a zero after?

Comment: did that, was searching is there is a function to do that other way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
number_format('3', 1, '.', ''); // = 3.0
number_format('3.', 1, '.', ''); // = 3.0
number_format('3.22', 1, '.', ''); // = 3.2
number_format('3.22abc', 1, '.', ''); // = 3.2 and a "PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered"
number_format('abc3.22', 1, '.', ''); // = "PHP Warning:  number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given"
```

Comment: what if my number is in string format? floatval is not converting it. Any idea?

Comment: I've echoed the result and it is 3.0... floatval will stop conversion on first non-number symbol, so "3", "3.", "3.1234567" will work. "3.123456abc" will give you a notice. "abc123" will give you a warning.

Comment: @amitchhajer - cast the number to a float first? 
Such as: number_format((float) '3.22', 1, '.', ''); 
The only drawback to this approach is that number_format returns a string and not a float or int.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [`number_format()`](http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for this.

`number_format($number, 1, ".", "");` will do the trick for you:

- `3` becomes `3.0`
- `2500` becomes `2500.0`

Comment: Yeah, it looks the the OP wants valid numbers, so change the fourth parameter from `" "` to `''`.

Comment: @RogueCoder Eh... it was an oversight. Thanks for the notice, I've edited the answer.

Comment: You actually need to add the '' as the fourth parameter since it defaults to ','.

Comment: @RogueCoder I didn't know that. Apparently, on my system it defaults to `''`. Might be locale differencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting it as a float first, and then using number_format to format it.

```
$number = (float) $_POST['text_box'];
number_format($number, 1, '.', '');
```

Hope this helps